# Ajax filter is not working properly

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have created an filter in my website using AJAX.Filtering is worked when I called the AJAX using click event on an interval fine .But When I am clicked the Submit button multiple times simultaneously I am getting the repeated result over my page.I am not gives here whole details .

I am appending the result in my page on the base of div count. That is the problem I think.

```
if ($("#holiday-list-loaded-view-start").nextAll("div").first().hasClass('hotel-list-view')) {
    $(".hotel-list-view").last().after('<div class="hotel-list-view"><div class="wrapper"><div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 switch-img clear-padding"><a href="'+base_url+'package_detail/view_detail/'+value["id"]+'"><img src="'+img+'"alt="cruise"></a></div><div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 hotel-info"><div><div class="hotel-header"><h5>'+value["package_name"].substr(0,120)+'<!--<span><i class="fa fa-star colored"></i><i class="fa fa-star colored"></i><i class="fa fa-star colored"></i><i class="fa fa-star colored"></i><i class="fa fa-star-o colored"></i></span>--></h5><p class="small"><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i>'+shortest_itinerary+'&nbsp<span  id="packagepopup'+value['id']+'" class="package_modal_details" ><i class="fa fa-info-circle" title="View Details" ></i></span><!--<i class="fa fa-phone"></i>123456789--></p></div><div class="hotel-header"><p>Inclusions</p></div><div class="hotel-desc"><p>'+inclusions+'</p></div><!--<div class="hotel-header"><p>Themes</p></div><div class="hotel-desc"><p>'+themes+'</p></div>--></div></div><div class="clearfix visible-sm-block"></div><div class="col-md-2 rating-price-box text-center clear-padding"><div class="rating-box"><div class=""><strong>Themes</strong></div><div class="small">'+themes+'</div></div><div class="room-book-box"><div class="price"><h5>Rs '+value["package_price"]+'/Person</h5></div><div class="book"><a href="#" class="send_package_query" id="packagequery'+value["id"]+'" title="Send a Query">QUERY</a><a href="'+base_url+'package_detail/view_detail/'+value["id"]+'" title="View Detail">DETAIL</a></div></div></div></div></div>'); 
} else {
    $("#holiday-list-loaded-view-start").after('<div class="hotel-list-view"><div class="wrapper"><div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 switch-img clear-padding"><a href="'+base_url+'package_detail/view_detail/'+value["id"]+'"><img src="'+img+'"alt="cruise"></a></div><div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 hotel-info"><div><div class="hotel-header"><h5>'+value["package_name"].substr(0,120)+'<!--<span><i class="fa fa-star colored"></i><i class="fa fa-star colored"></i><i class="fa fa-star colored"></i><i class="fa fa-star colored"></i><i class="fa fa-star-o colored"></i></span>--></h5><p class="small"><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i>'+shortest_itinerary+'<span  id="packagepopup'+value['id']+'" class="package_modal_details" ><i class="fa fa-info-circle" title="View Details" ></i></span><!--<i class="fa fa-phone"></i>123456789--></p></div><div class="hotel-header"><p>Inclusions</p></div><div class="hotel-desc"><p>'+inclusions+'</p></div><!--<div class="hotel-header"><p>Themes</p></div><div class="hotel-desc"><p>'+themes+'</p></div>--></div></div><div class="clearfix visible-sm-block"></div><div class="col-md-2 rating-price-box text-center clear-padding"><div class="rating-box"><div class=""><strong>Themes</strong></div><div class="small">'+themes+'</div></div><div class="room-book-box"><div class="price"><h5>Rs '+value["package_price"]+'/Person</h5></div><div class="book"> <a href="#" class="send_package_query" id="packagequery'+value["id"]+'" title="Send a Query">QUERY</a><a href="'+base_url+'package_detail/view_detail/'+value["id"]+'" title="View Detail">DETAIL</a></div></div></div></div></div>'); 
}
```

Oh yeah I got It when the page is rendered .It takes Time mean while if another filtering event occur then Its result is also appended to the same block due to the improper match of div element therefor result is repeated.

But How to resolve It. I don't know.

Comment: What is `.ajax_calls`?

Comment: This is a function which takes the input form and pagination page detail and renders the results. I have update my question

Comment: I have two div #holiday-list-loaded-view-start and #holiday-list-loaded-view-end b/w them I am rendering my results

Comment: Not certain what issue is? Can you create a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net to demonstrate?

Comment: This is It https://jsfiddle.net/4fcoq0o5/

Comment: Can you narrow `javascript` to portions which cause issue?

Comment: I have some bad coding style.It will not be easier to understand that but every thing in this make sense.

Answer (score 0):

then make use of `empty()` function to clear previous result(the possible place is just before loop starts),

```
//this will erase previous result
$(".hotel-list-view").empty();
// or 
 $("#holiday-list-loaded-view-start").empty();
// then append function may be before/after/append
```

Comment: let me know whether answer is helpful to you or not

Comment: Yes your answer is helpful but I am using this $( "#holiday-grid-loaded-view-start" ).nextUntil('#holiday-grid-loaded-view-end').remove(); for proper result.